# Eclipse external libraries

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently experiencing issues whilst using external libraries in Eclipse. Whenever I am trying to launch my program it throws a NoClassDefFound exception. I am obviously doing something wrong. Could someone re-explain for me how to properly include them into your project? (Yes I have already done a lot of research on this and got recommended to use Maven dependencies which I don‘t want. Also I have found some threads that were more relevant to my issue but nothing helped. So yeah, I would really appreciate it if someone could explain what exactly to do.)

I am using the newest ver of eclipse together with java 8 (usually 13 but that did not fix my error). It only throws the exception on runtime so, it compiles without any errors.

Project setup: http://prntscr.com/udsxts

Manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: me.sxlver.consoleclient.Main
Class-Path: lib/java-json.jar lib/snakeyaml-1.26.jar
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
        at me.sxlver.consoleclient.Main.main(Main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

(I am just creating an instance of JSONObject)

Java Build Path: http://prntscr.com/udtgjn

Libraries: http://prntscr.com/udtqas

Comment: In the screenshot please expand _Referenced Libraries > java-json.jar_ to show that you have the right JAR that contains `org.json.JSONObject`. Please also add the command line to your question (in the run configuration there is a button _Show Command Line_ for that).

Comment: I've attached a screenshot of the Build Path to the thread. At this point i think that the run configuration is the issue since i haven't changed anything right there. May you have an explenation of what i should do?

Comment: The things shown look good. If deleting the launch configuration and right-clicking _Run As > Java Application_ does not help, show the command line (see my last comment how to get the command line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the *Run* menu, select *Run Configurations...*

[image]

Select *Dependencies* tab, then click on button *Add External JARs*

[image]

A file chooser window will appear. Navigate to the location of the relevant JAR and select it.

Comment: It looks like that for me: http://prntscr.com/udu2lx

Comment: @Sxlver click on _User Entries_ in order to enable the button _Add External JARs_

Comment: Well, it works when I'm trying to run it inside eclipse (I guess that already worked before) The issue is that it throws an exception when exported from eclipse.

Comment: @Sxlver that's an entirely different problem. It has to do with the _Class-Path_ header in the manifest of the JAR file you are exporting. I suggest you ask a new question. You are creating a JAR file in Eclipse and when you run the JAR file you get `NoClassDefFoundError`. So you want to know how to export a JAR file in Eclipse such that it can access external JARs when you run it. Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: My apologies, I thought i would've mentioned that in my question. I will create a new one, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is due to the build path was setup incorrectly. What I normally do is:

1. Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Build Path` -> `User Library` -> `New Library` -> Add `jar` (your `lib` files).
2. Right click on your project -> `Build Path` -> `Add Libraries` -> `Add User Libraries` -> `Done`.

Comment: I suppose that I am using the build path correctly. I suspect the run configuration to be the issue at this point. Haven't ever used the run configuration yet. Gotta figure out how to use it properly.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you also post a screen shot of Java Build Path (Libraries)? Also, extend all the component in that page.

Comment: They're containing the JSONObject. Something goes wrong whilest the code compilation due to wrong settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what worked was:  Right-click project -> Build Path -> Add External Archives...